# Plot a region between two curves that is below another in $R^3$

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

I am trying to obtain a 3D plot of $z=x^2+2y^2$ that is bound by the region in the $z=0$ plane governed by the equations $y=x$ and $y=x^2$.  Is it possible to do this with `RegionFunction`? or `RegionPlot3D`?

Answer (score 2):

This should work, if I understood your question correctly:

```
Plot3D[
  x^2 + 2 y^2,
  {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[x^2 <= y <= x, {x, y}]
]
```

[image: 3D plot of a slice]

Comment: Thanks.  That worked perfectly.  I am new to this and was not aware of the Implicit Region.

Comment: @GeorgeE Great, glad it helped! If you find my answer useful, you can upvote it for now and, eventually, accept is by clicking on the gray checkmark beside it.